# How do I check if a user exists in puppet?

Tags: puppet, scripting

I already found some examples where I can check if a variable has a specific value

```
if $var == 'somevalue' {
    ...
}
```

of if something is defined

```
if defined(Package['somepackage']) {
    ...
}
```

but how can I check if a user exists and fail if it doesn't. It would be sufficient to know how to use the result of a script or shell test because `/usr/bin/id -u ${name} >/dev/null 2>&1` is all I need, even a check if the user directory exists would be ok.

`file` and `exec` do not accept the `onlyif` parameter, otherwise this wouldn't be a problem at all

Comment: An what if you just use `ensure` parameter of [`user`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#user)?

Comment: would that just fail if the user doesn't exist or would it try to create that user?

Comment: I think if you set `ensure=present` it would create user and do nothing if the user exist.

Comment: OK, that was what I thought/was afraid of. I don't want to create a user, i just want to do some things if it exists. Thanks anyway, found something else useful in the puppet reference you linked. But my main problem remains...

Comment: And what about using `require => User['foo'],` for what you want to do?

Comment: Doesn't help either. `Could not find dependency User[***]` because I haven't defined the User in puppet.

Comment: I split my class into a class and a define and created the User ressource in between. Looks like a hack to me but it works.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just add in a facter fact and check on it?

with my setup on puppet 3, I'd place the following into `modules/facts/lib/facter/user_exists_blah.rb`

```
require 'facter'
Facter.add(:user_exists_blah) do
  setcode do
    name = "blah"
    Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("/usr/bin/id -u #{name} 2>/dev/null")
  end
end
```

And then use it as

```
if $::user_exists_blah {
}
```

An empty string evaluates to false, so you can just use it as a boolean

Comment: That looks like what I want to do. Is it also possible to parametrize this facter (give the user name as a parameter)?

Comment: Sadly AFAIK, no, you can't

Comment: You can have a Facter fact return *all* the users on the system, though, and have the master make decisions based on that.

Comment: That's actually a really good point jgoldschrafe! Thanks for that insight.

Comment: You implementation always returns an empty string. I changed the command to "/usr/bin/id -u #{name} 2>/dev/null". Now the variable $user_exists_blah in the if-statement is truthy (non empty string containing the uid) or falsy (an empty string).

Comment: Thanks for the fix geekQ, it's been updated. I had copied and pasted the user code from the question and didn't notice that it destroyed stdout and stderr.

Comment: Note that facts can only be strings, so you'll need to return a comma-separated list of names and split it in your manifest/template.

Comment: Doing an exec of the id program is silly when Ruby has `etc::getpwnam`.  As far back as 1.8.7, there's https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-getpwnam

Answer (score 0):

in case this helps somebody, for my purposes it was more efficient to do:

lib/facter/system_users.rb:

```
require 'facter'

Facter.add(:system_users) do
  setcode do
    Facter::Core::Execution.exec('/usr/bin/cut -f 1 -d \':\' /etc/passwd | /usr/bin/tr \'\n\' \':\'')
  end
end
```

and then:

```
$system_user_list = $facts['system_users']
$system_users = split($system_user_list,':')
if ($site_user in $system_users) { ...
```